# Divide a python list into subsets of lists (the smaller the number of subsets the better), each with sum less then K

Tags: python, list

I am fairly new to python. I am making a program and am stuck with a problem that can be summed up as follows:

Lets say we have a list of numbers (each is less than 5) `[1.5, 3, 4, 2.5 , 1, 4, 0.5 etc]`. I want to divide this list into subsets of list, with the condition that the sum of items in each subset is `<= 5`. The list can have up to 200 items.

The optimal solution would be the one that returns the **smallest** number of subsets. But I am not looking for an optimal solution, just a **good enough** one.

Comment: It's important to keep the list and its subsets ordered? (in you example the solution should be `[[1.5, 3], [4], [2.5, 1], [4, 0.5]]`)

Comment: is there some other condition you didnt mention? Cuz you could just return a single subset with a single number that's <=5 and iiuc satisfy what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). It is a well-studied NP-complete problem, meaning that no known algorithm gives exact answers (i.e. with the true minimum number of sublists) while also running efficiently for larger inputs.

However, since you only need a "good" enough solution, you are in luck; there are many good [heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Analysis_of_approximate_algorithms) which give quite good answers in practice. A nice simple one is the "First Fit Decreasing" algorithm:

1. Sort the items in descending order (i.e. largest first).
2. Initialise a list to store the sublists in. Initially, there are none.
3. For each item:

   - If there are any sublists with sufficient remaining capacity, insert the item into the first one.
   - Otherwise, create a new empty sublist, and insert the item there.

This turns out to always give solutions using at most (11/9)b + 1 sublists, where b is the number of sublists used by an optimal solution ([Yue, 1990](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02009683)).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I adopted a similar approach after posting the question. It is nice to confirm that it is a good enough one. The paper looks quite interesting thank you for linking it.

Answer (score 1):

I would contest that this is more of an algorithm problem than it is python-specific - but one algorithm that pops in to my head that feels simple enough would be to sort the list, and create "buckets" (sub-lists) that start with the max element, and add from the front of the list until it cannot be added.

In Python that might look something like list

```py
x = [1.5, 3, 4, 2.5 , 1, 4, 0.5]
x.sort()
buckets = []

while True:
    # if the list is empty, break
    if x == []:
        break

    last_elem = x.pop()  # pop removes the last element and returns it
    new_bucket = [last_elem]  # create a new bucket initially with just that
    new_bucket_sum = last_elem

    # for the remaining numbers
    num_added = 0
    for num in x:
        if num + new_bucket_sum > 5:
            break
        new_bucket.append(num) # add it to the sub-list
        new_bucket_sum += num  # account for the sum
        num_added += 1  # increase our count for this iteration

    buckets.append(new_bucket)  # add the bucket
    x = x[num_added:]  # take a sub-list of x (getting rid of the numbers added)


    # Note that we now recurse until all numbers have been placed in to buckets

# After this for loop breaks, you have all the buckets
print(buckets)
```

This was my go-to instinct. There are more "pythonic" ways I'd say to write that algorithm but since you are new to Python I thought it may be helpful to break it up and comment. There also may be better algorithms out there. Cheers

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. You are right this is more of an algorithm type problem but your python illustration is quite helpful. I ended up adopting a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought to add that if the elements of the resulting list-of-lists MUST maintain their original ordering (with respect to the input list), then you can do this:

```py
elts = [1.5, 3, 4, 2.5 , 1, 4, 0.5]
res = []

temp = []      # for accumulating the numbers
temp_sum = 0   # the sum of the accumulated numbers

for e in elts:
    temp_sum += e    # update the sum with current element
    if temp_sum > 5:
        # if updating the sum with the current element
        # makes the sum overshoot the limit
        # then don't accumulate the current element
        # instead ...
        res.append(temp)  # append the previously accumulated elements to the result
        temp = [e]        # start a new accumulator with the current element
        temp_sum = e      # start a new accumulated sum with the current element
    else:
        # if updating the sum with the current element
        # does not make the sum overshoot the limit ...
        temp.append(e)    # accumulate current element

# finally, append the last seen accumulator to the result
res.append(temp)
```

The result, res, will be `[[1.5, 3], [4], [2.5, 1], [4, 0.5]]`

Answer (score 0):

I liked the challenge, so I create a [heuristic algorythm](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Heuristic_algorithms) based on **random sampling** of the base list. Thus it search for the best solution, until a preset given iteration number:

```
import numpy as np


#base_randlist = np.random.random(200) * 5

base_randlist = np.array([1.5, 3, 4, 2.5 , 1, 4, 0.5])

print(base_randlist)

sets = []
for i in range(10000):

    set_ = []
    subset = []
    randlist = base_randlist

    while randlist.shape[0] != 0:
        while True:
            if randlist.shape[0] == 0:
                set_.append(subset)
                break
            ind = np.random.randint(0, randlist.shape[0])
            last_subset = subset.copy()
            subset.append(randlist[ind])

            if sum(subset) <= 5:
                randlist = np.delete(randlist, ind)
            else:
                set_.append(last_subset)
                subset = []
                break
    sets.append(set_)

min_setnum = np.inf
for i, s in enumerate(sets):
    if min_setnum > len(s):
        min_setnum = len(s)
        min_ind = i

print(sets[min_ind])
print(min_setnum)
```

**Out:**

```
[1.5 3.  4.  2.5 1.  4.  0.5]
[[3.0, 0.5], [1.5, 2.5], [4.0], [4.0, 1.0]]
4
```